# Is there a way using javax.validation to validate that a date is larger / less than or between specific dates?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I know of `@Future` and `@Past` but they compare to the local VM system date. What am I missing?

Comment: Good point, but then you take all the essence out of annotations. They are all mostly sysntactic sugars for lazy, ehm. I mean sofisticated programmers. Why do you need @RequestParam @ModelAttribute etc. you can write one line of code to replace them. But if we go toward keepin common task automated using Annotations, why do half of the job...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is an annotation in javax.validation that does what you want, but you can always create your own validator by extending the ConstraintValidator interface. You can see an example here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html

Comment: It's a pity there isn't an out-of-the-box solution for this. I wonder why `@Min` and `@Max` weren't designed to support date types.

Comment: `http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html` is a dead link